# Copy widget settings from one blog to another

Tags: widgets, plugins

I am trying to hook 'wpmu_new_blog' in a plugin so I can copy the widget settings from one blog to the new blog that is being created.

Does anyone know if there are WordPress functions to accomplish this, or should I just use straight SQL?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything specifically for this. You might want to look at the plugin code to find calls to `get_option()` and see what keys they are using, then browse the DB table `wp_options` with phpMyAdmin (or whatever) and grab the associated values.

Without specific support from the plugin this can be iffy since there may be other context-dependent info in there that you don't want on the new site.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. I wish WordPress didn't store widget settings in such a funky way. I guess I'll try doing it with SQL. Thanks for your help, Dave

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve this problem manually by hooking wpmu_new_blog with this code:

```
global $wpdb;

$option_names = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name LIKE 'widget_%' OR option_name LIKE 'sidebars_%';");

$widget_options = array();
foreach ($option_names as $option_name) {
    $widget_options["$option_name->option_name"] = get_option($option_name->option_name);
}

switch_to_blog($blog_id);

delete_option( 'widget_search', array ( 2 => array ( 'title' => '' ), '_multiwidget' => 1 ) );
delete_option( 'widget_recent-posts', array ( 2 => array ( 'title' => '', 'number' => 5 ), '_multiwidget' => 1 ) );
delete_option( 'widget_recent-comments', array ( 2 => array ( 'title' => '', 'number' => 5 ), '_multiwidget' => 1 ) );
delete_option( 'widget_archives', array ( 2 => array ( 'title' => '', 'count' => 0, 'dropdown' => 0 ), '_multiwidget' => 1 ) );
delete_option( 'widget_categories', array ( 2 => array ( 'title' => '', 'count' => 0, 'hierarchical' => 0, 'dropdown' => 0 ), '_multiwidget' => 1 ) );
delete_option( 'widget_meta', array ( 2 => array ( 'title' => '' ), '_multiwidget' => 1 ) );

foreach ($widget_options as $option_name => $option_value) {
    update_option($option_name, $option_value);
}

restore_current_blog();
```

Not the best code in the world, but it gets the job done, I suppose.